# Namespace not found visual studio form based application

Tags: c#

I'm trying to make an application to add and retrieve credentials in windows vault. I used the following code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var vault = new PasswordVault();
    var credential = new PasswordCredential(RESOURCE_NAME, userName, password);
    vault.Add(credential);
}
```

It says `PasswordVault();` and `PasswordCredential` namespace could not find. How to fix this?

Comment: Are you sure you add necessary assembly and using directive to your project?

Comment: Hi Soner Gönül, I'm just beginner in C#. I've made simple application using C#. I don't know how to do it

Answer (score 1):

The class you are using is part of the [Windows.Security.Credentials namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.security.credentials.aspx).

In your file header just add

```
using  Windows.Security.Credentials;
```

For additional information, check out Microsoft documentation on [PasswordVault class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.security.credentials.passwordvault.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1).

Comment: Hi K.B thanks for your reply. I have already tried that. But it says
The type or namespace name 'windows' could not be found. I'm using visual studio ultimate 2013.

Comment: I can add using  Windows.Security.Credentials;  if i select a blank application. But shows error in form based application. I need a GUI. How to solve this?

Comment: Hi finally I figured out it from https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/using-winrt-apis-from-desktop-applications
Thank you all :)

Comment: @user2689288, If that linked solved your problem you asked the wrong question.